# Excel how to repeat text to columns depending on entries and insert columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My spreadsheet has variable number of comma separated entries in multiple columns.  I need to calculate for each column the max number of entries, insert this many blank columns and then run the text to columns function.  Then I need to repeat this on any other columns in the spreadsheet that have more than 1 comma separated entry.
For example:

Column 1: Row 1 = 2 entries, Row 3 = 5 entries

Column 2: Row 1 = 6 entries, Row 30 = 4 entries

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you definitely need VBA for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert one column to the right of your comma separated values column
2. Enter formula in the new row for each respective cell

   `=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1`
3. Result tells you how many fields are within a given cell (number of commas plus "1")
4. Via sort or `=max(...)` formula, determine the greatest number; insert the number of empty columns for a given reference column for your desired purpose.

If this solution solves your problem, please mark it as answered.